# Django trying to add images with forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have two models with two different forms. One has a ForeignKey for another model, making a 1-N relationship. The problem is when i try to add images , is not working. The form where i change the (*name*/TabletForm2) is working so , only when i try to add (*image*/TabletFormImagem) is not working.

The problem is that

**My model's**

```js
    def get_image(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join('intervencao/fotografias', str(instance.intervencao), filename)

    class Intervencao(models.Model):
      name= models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
      
    class Imagem(models.Model):
        intervencao = models.ForeignKey(Intervencao, related_name='intervencaoObjectsImagem', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Fotografia")

        def __str__(self, ):
            return str(self.intervencao)
```

**My View**

```js
def project_detail_chefe(request, pk):
    form = TabletForm2(request.POST)
    form2 = TabletFormImagem(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:   
            form = TabletForm2(request.POST)
            
        if form2.is_valid():
            //when i print something here to see if the form2 is valid , never enter here.
            form2.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form2 = TabletFormImagem()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'form2':form2,
    }
    return render(request, 'tablet/info_chefes.html', context)
```

**tablet/info_chefes.html**

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class='form-group'>
      <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}" id="titulo">Name:</label>
        <em>{{ form.name}}</em>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form2.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Forms**

```js
class TabletForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Intervencao
        fields = ['data_intervencao_fim','ferramenta']


class TabletFormImagem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Imagem
        fields = ['imagem']
```

Comment: return redirect('index') and  return redirect('home') why?

Comment: that was another error i forget to change there, i already update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def project_detail_chefe(request, pk):
    form = TabletForm2()
    form2 = TabletFormImagem()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TabletForm2(request.POST)
        form2 = TabletFormImagem(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            instance_form1 = form.save()
            instance_form2 = form2.save(commit=False)
            instance_form2.intervencao = instance_form1
            instance_form2.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:   
            form = TabletForm2()
            form2 = TabletFormImagem()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'form2':form2,
    }
    return render(request, 'tablet/info_chefes.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class='form-group'>
        <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}" id="titulo">Name:</label>
          <em>{{ form.name}}</em>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form2.as_p }}
           <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yeh is working pretty good , my error was having two forms where I didn't need.Thanks!!!

Comment: I noticed now that, when inserting the data and if not putting any image, it still creates an empty object